# Finding the projection of a characteristic curve (method of characteristics)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> When does the equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{b}{a}$ represents the slope of the projection of the characteristic curve of $au_x + bu_y = c$ onto the $x,y$ plane and why? How is equation obtained from the characteristic equations?

In general, the method of characteristics works for $a(x,y,u)u_x + b(x,y,u)u_y = c(x,y,u)$ (quasi-linear PDEs) and allows one to build the solution surface as a union of characteristics.
What I can't understand is how we can move from the characteristic equations
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = a , \, \frac{dy}{dt}=b, \, \frac{du}{dt}=c,
$$
to the equations $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{b}{a}, \, \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{c}{a}$ or even more generally to
$$
\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b} = \frac{du}{c}.
$$
I guess these have something to do with the chain rule, but can't find any good resource that explains it thoroughly.

Hope I stated the question clearly enough. Thank you

Comment: It is just eliminating the parameterisation in terms of $t$. Integrate each equation to get $$x=at+x_{0}, y=bt+y_{0}, u=ct+u_{0}$$ and convert from parametric to Cartesian form $$\frac{x-x_{0}}{a} = \frac{y-y_{0}}{b} = \frac{u-u_{0}}{c} = t$$ If we compute the total differential of each expression, we have $$\frac{dx}{a} = \frac{dy}{b} = \frac{du}{c} = dt$$ Note you don't need to do the integration though. You can just compute the total differential of $u$ directly and equate to the PDE $$du=u_{x}dx+u_{y}dy=au_{x}+bu_{y}=c$$ and so $$dx=a, dy=b, du=c \implies dx/a=dy/b=du/c=1$$

Comment: Thank you for the comment @mattos , but as I mentioned, $a,b,c$ are functions of $x,y,u$ which makes most of the calculations you mentioned irrelevant, right?

Comment: No, they aren't irrelevant. The point was to show how the parameterisation gives the same results and that the parameterisation is unnecessary (note I just gave an example with $a, b, c$ constant to begin so I could integrate with respect to $t$, though I probably should have stated this). You can use the total differential result. It does not matter if $a, b, c$ are functionally dependent on the system coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first point
   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{b}{a}$$
   The second point:
   $$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\frac{du}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{c}{a}$$
2. Basically, a symmetric form of ODE system is just a convenient way to write it down.
   Say, we have a system of n ODEs
   $$\frac{dx_1}{ds} = F_1(x_1, ..., x_n),...,\frac{dx_n}{ds} = F_n(x_1, ..., x_n)$$
   We can rewrite it as
   $$\frac{dx_1}{F_1(x_1, ..., x_n)} = ds,...,\frac{dx_n}{F_n(x_1, ..., x_n)} = ds$$
   Now each expression is equal to $ds$, so we can rewrite it as a chain equality:
   $$\frac{dx_1}{F_1(x_1, ..., x_n)} = ... = \frac{dx_n}{F_n(x_1, ..., x_n)} = ds$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As for the first point - how did you deduce that $y$ is effectively a function of $x$?

Comment: @Dr.John, sorry, I'd mistaken — edited the answer